# open() method I/O error

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I'm trying to write all the settings from each run of a program to a config file.

This line is giving me strange issues:

```
cfgfile = open(config_filename, 'w+')
```

I am getting I/O Errors of the 'No such file or directory' kind. This happens no matter if the flag is w+, a, etc.

I am creating the config_filename from a string stored in a dictionary, concatenated with another short string:

```
config_filename = my_dict['key'] + '_PARAMETERS.txt'
```

This is what seems to be causing the problems. I have tested with using

```
config_filename = 'test' + '_PARAMETERS.txt'
```

and it works fine, creating the file before writing to it.

Can anyone explain why this happens, I have checked I'm in the same directory and type(config_filename) throws back string as expected. Is this something to do with how dicts store data?

Thanks.

Comment: What data contains my_dict?

Comment: can you print the config_filename for which you are getting the issue?

Comment: The dictionary stores a whole load of variables and parameters for the program. The entry I use is a string created from the current time and date which I use for results output. I have tested the type() and it is still str

Comment: Have you escaped slashes in my_dict?

Comment: The config_filename is in the format: Results_15/07/15_18:32:09_PARAMETERS.txt

Comment: You can get such error if my_dict['key'] contains date in format like "...10/10/15..."

Comment: Ahh, that would be the problem then. Workaround?

Comment: As option you could replace backslashes in your path with '_' symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you're trying to create a file with a name that includes slashes. This will fail because slashes are not allowed in file names, as they are reserved by the OS to indicate the directory structure. Colons are also not allowed in Windows file names.

Try replacing `my_dict['key']` with `my_dict['key'].replace('/', '')`, which will remove the slashes and produce a filename like `Results_150715_18:32:09_PARAMETERS.txt`. For Windows, add `.replace(':','')` to remove the colon as well.

I should clarify that slashes are not allowed in file *names*, but they are allowed in file *paths*. The filename you were trying to use would have attempted to create a file named `15_18:32:09_PARAMETERS.txt` in the `07` folder, contained in the `Results_15` folder. That isn't what you wanted, but it wouldn't have failed as long as the directory structure existed (on Windows, anyway). Additionally, Windows systems don't allow colons anywhere in the path except to indicate the drive, e.g. `C:`.